# Entityreference multiple choice

Tags: 7, entities

I have an entityreference field on users and I can't find a way to select more than one value. I want to make like a multiple select, but with the entityreference.

I use the EntityReference module, here is my form item :

```
$form['maj_planning']['suivi_par'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entityreference',
  '#title' => t('Suivi par'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $entity->suivi_par,
  '#era_entity_type' => 'user',
  '#era_bundles' => array(),
  '#era_cardinality' => 1,
  '#era_query_settings' => array(
    'limit' => 15, // Default is 50.
    'property_conditions' => array(),
    'field_conditions' => array(),
  ),
);
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .theme file:

```
function MyTheme_user_form_user_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['maj_planning']['suivi_par']['#multiple'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: In what content type can I choose unlimited ? My entityreference is on users, and my content types doesn't make sense about a search on users (I have blog page, page, slideshow, webform)

Comment: check my update please.